# Decreasing the outer margin

Tags: margins, memoir

How can I decrease the outer margin for the pages of my `memoir` book, without decreasing the inner margin?

I want to alter the settings I already have, given here:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\dimexpr 6in-15mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{510pt}{270pt}{*}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{4}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{2}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{45.23mm}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{3.0\baselineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `\textwidth` immediately before `\checkandfixthelayout`. If you add a positive value to `\textwidth`, yo have to add the corresponding negative value to `\foremargin`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\dimexpr 6in-15mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{510pt}{270pt}{*}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{4}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{2}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{45.23mm}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{3.0\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{10pt}
\addtolength{\foremargin}{-10pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This might be a separate question, but maybe you have a simple answer--is there now a way to increase the inner margin?  (while leaving the outer margin the way it is in your example)

Comment: @jamaicanworm I guess you could increase the value of `\spinemargin` by X pt, while at the same time removing X pt from the changes to `\textwidth`/`foremargin`.

Comment: @jamaicanworm Correction: Remove X pt from the changes to `\textwidth` , but *not* from the changes to `\foremargin`.